# Store and export raw tokens in a solr index

Tags: csv, solr, lucene, token

I'd like to store tokens generated by Solr during indexing, such as `DictionaryCompoundWordToken` and then export them, hopefully using `CSVResponseWriter`.  Is there a way to do that?

I know it's possible to use the Analysis tool to provide values and see how they are tokenized, but I am unaware of how to do this for entirety of the index, or at least on a query basis.

Comment: 1) In your case, will the contents of your text go into one field say "text" ? 2) Are you expecting anything more than just the tokens?

Comment: 1) Yes 2) No, just the tokens it generates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see, I think what you want is to store, alongside the original content of some field, the field value but after it goes through some analysis chain, right?

You would think copyFields would help, but they don't as if you store them, the original field value is stored. You need to use an updateProcessor. Look at [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXSK2RvVJsk) Erik Hatcher gave, minutes 7:30 to 20:00 aprox, and you will see exactly this case explained very well, with examples and all.

Once you have that stored in the index, you can return it and do anything you like.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks very much.  A simple Script based UpdateProcessor was all I needed to get at the tokens

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at this is this, you will index your document content into a field "mytext" with your `DictionaryCompoundWordToken` or any other analysis that fits your needs. Then you can facet on "mytext" with q=*:* ,  your query would look like this : `http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&start=0&rows=1&wt=xml&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=mytext` That should give all the tokens that went into mytext.  But i am not 100% sure of your expectation with what you said in the question. Let me  know this helps.

Comment: how does the tokens are stored, as I see if its not indexed as a part of fields we can't offer facet on that! Can you share how we can convert these tokens and store it in index so it can be offered as facet.